# How to prevent the entry of more than ten digits and also letters and symbols in python

Tags: python

I started learning Python, and I was working on a simple draft number manual, and I had a problem of only 10 digits and no letters or symbols.
this is my code

```py
number = 10
def num():

    number = input("Enter the number")

    if number == "1111111111":
        print("Amal")

    elif number == "2222222222":
        print("Mohammed")

    elif number == "3333333333":
        print("Khadijah")

    elif number == "4444444444":
        print("Abdullah")

    elif number == "5555555555":
        print("Rawan")

    elif number == "6666666666":
        print("Faisal")

    elif number == "7777777777":
        print("Layla")

    else:
       print("Sorry, the number is not found ")
num()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to differentiate the error message for a non-found number and an invalid entry, you would need the following:

1- To check if the input is numeric or if it contains any other symbols, you can use the following:

```
if number.isdigit():
   print("Is a number!")
else:
   print("Not a number!")
```

2- To check for the length, you can simply use:

```
if len(number) == 10:
   print("is 10 digits!")
else:
   print("Not 10 digits")
```